# Format flash problem on Boox M92

Tags: ebook-readers

My Boox M92 e-reader is brand new. I realized that internal storage was roughly 2GB/3GB full. (In fact it should have 4GB in total)

I tried to format flash as I had nothing anyway, except maybe a test scribbles.
After the format my internal storage is 3149MB/3149MB full and the same is after the restart, after another format...

Is anyone familiar with the problem? Is this a bug in memory info or is it a bug in flash format procedure?? Should I try to fix it or return the product?

Answer (score 1):

The M92 manual says:

> Format Flash
>
> Select Format Flash button in settings, you can format the
> internal flash. Note, after doing this operation all of the data
> in internal flash would be removed

From the internal flash memory, some should be reserved for databases containing the metadata of your ebooks and other content. Even empty databases take up some space.

2-3Gb out of 4Gb seems excessive for that, but only another Boox M92 user can really give you a comparable figure. As a comparison: My Cybook Odessey HD has 135Mb used from the 1.5Gb internal flash memory.

On the other hand I think you can expect such a device to complain if flash memory cannot be properly formatted.